# How should I avoid this reflexive pronoun, or is it okay?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, reflexives

I typed a sentence in Microsoft Word as:

> - Each mobile operating system implements encryption in their own way.

It was part of a list of bullet points. I got dinged for ***their own*** being grammatically incorrect, and the error was

> Reflexive Pronoun Use (consider revising)

My question: What is a reflexive pronoun? Also, is there a better way to word this, or is it fine as is? I know software won't have all the nuances of the English language correct, but as I don't know who will be viewing this document in the future, I'd like to have all my Pronouns in a row.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Rule One: Never accept what Microsoft's grammar checker says as gospel.

In this case, it has mis-identified *their* as a reflexive pronoun. That name is generally reserved for pronouns like *themselves*.

However, it has correctly identified that *their* does not match anything else in the sentence, which is all singular. While you can use *their* as a singular sexless pronoun [according to many], in this case "Each mobile system" does not need a sexless pronoun, and ***its*** would be correct.

> - Each mobile operating system implements encryption in its own way.

Comment: Rule Two: Turn off Microsoft's grammar checker.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence you wrote is ungrammatical.
If the subject of the sentence were a person of unknown gender, you could use the ugly *singular **they/their/them*** construction, but because the subject is *Each mobile operating system*, you must use ***its*** own way. It's not a [reflexive pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_pronoun): that would be "*itself*".